# Integrate Spring Rest Services with Spring Security JWT deployed separately

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-rest, spring-security-rest

I have a Spring JWT Project and Spring Rest Services which are deployed separately. I have to do authentication and authorization stuff by calling Spring JWT Service. I'm new to this though but I have good understanding. Any one having idea how to achieve this.

Note:
Spring 4.x, Spring Security 4.x and Hibernate 5.x with Java based configuration

Comment: I've successfully implemented a spring rest project with spring security with JWT. Cant understand what do you mean by _Spring JWT project_. And '_deployed separately_'

Comment: I mean Spring Security with Jwt is the project I'm are using for the Authentication and Authorization Stuff. In my actual project, I would be hitting the endpoint of Spring Security with JWT for validating the token.

Comment: As per my understanding, I dont think you can create a separate Spring Security project to do auth stuff for your actual Spring Rest project. All you need to do is, integrate Spring Security in your actual Spring Rest project.

Comment: I was able implement this by using custom AuthenticationTokenFilter.

Comment: Please share your solution as answer and mark as accepted.